# Custom Routing URL in MVC (appurl/{uniqueId}/{controller}/{action}/{id})

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are trying to build an mvc application in c#. We want to change the routing config in such a way that it has uniqueId in between domain url and controller name.The uniqueId is dynamic and based on uniqueId the application will be connecting to there respective database through elastic database server.

The problem is that mvc is considering uniqueId as a controller. When i searched i found few solutions where uniqueId is static and is already defined.Please find the link for error image  [link](https://ibb.co/y89KVN8)

**For Example:** 
**I want to build something like shown below and it is not working**

***URL*: portal.example.com/{uniqueId}/Account/login**

***RouteConfig*:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{uniqueId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional, uniqueId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Please help us with this approach. Is there any other way to get this working. Thanks in advance

**Edit: Sorry for having hostname instead of uniqueId in defaults.I edited to uniqueid**

Comment: It should be working fine. Is there any other `routes` defined?

Comment: Hi Karan, only this is the routes configured in application

Comment: Are you using web-api or web-application? You have mention two different urls, one in title as `api/{uniqueId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and another on in description as `portal.example.com/{uniqueId}/Account/login` which one is actually in use?

Comment: Hi Karan, Sorry for the typo error. It is appurl (Web application).

Comment: I've tried with same and it is working for me. Just remove `hostname` from `defaults` as it is not in use.

Comment: Hi Karan,  Sorry for having hostname instead of uniqueId in defaults in question description.i edited with uniqueId.

Answer (score 1):

Write this on `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

After that, write this top on your controller.

```
[Route("your_controller/your_ındex")]
```

Comment: Hi Eren, 

Thanks for reply. I was looking for solution like Azure devops application url. if you look at Azure devops, its multi-tenancy application serving several customers.  **for example: dev.azure.com/{clientname}** - the client name can be anything and that will act as tenantid for elastic database pool. i tried implementing this solution, but MVC framework is not supporting such pattern and its considering {clientname} as controller name. please let me know if there is any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The URLs generated in Route Table are at the time of Application Start. They will remain static throughout.

One workaround is this:-

```
[NonAction]
public static string GetGuid()
{
    string myUniqueID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //My Unique ID Logic


    return myUniqueID;
}
```

You can call this throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code by just adding 'uniqueid' to defaults and it works fine for me

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{uniqueId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { uniqueId = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional, hostname = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Hi Ecstatic, I am getting the following error. Please find the image link [link](https://ibb.co/y89KVN8)

Comment: are you sure, you added 'uniqueId = UrlParameter.Optional' in defaults object.

Comment: Hi Ecstatic, Sorry for having hostname instead of uniqueId in defaults in question description.i edited with uniqueId

yes Ecstatic, I have added uniqueId in defaults